# uploading image to php with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, upload

I have been reading how to upload a simple image file .png fileformat and I have seen examples using some great plugings. I have tried those examples without success.

Here is a simple example. The scenario is: upload a simlpe .png image upon clicking a button using jquery ajax to php. I want to encode the file object as json to send it to the server side.

HERES IS THE HTML:

```
<div id="img_upload_container">
       <form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input name="image" type="file" />
          <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
       </form>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
$("form#data").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($(this));
    var data = JSON.stringify({action:'save_picture', 'picture':formData});
    console.log(data)
   var request= $.ajax({
                  url: "http://www.test.dev/picture",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: data,
                  processData: false,
                  contentType:'application/json'
    });
   request.done(function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
   });

});
```

THE SERVER SIDE:
Actually this is not the problem. I can handle this fine. I am using laravel and it has good file handling options. I don't know yet if want to save it in filesystem or a RDBMS. So I just want to make sure I am sending a valid file for later manipulation regardless of what I end up doing in the server side.

PROBLEM: `Console.log(data)` shows an empty `formData` eventhough there I am choosing a valid .png file.

QUESTION: What am I missing. This is the first time i have to save a picture file. I don't want to use a plugin for this. So please spare me if this is a dumb question.

Comment: If this is for a real-time site (that is, it is not merely an exercise to learn), then try this: [jquery upload file plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php). I've tried rolling my own many times, and Ravi's plugin is just solid. I use it on tons of sites. Highly recommended.

Comment: Have you tried using `<input type="submit" value='Submit' />` instead of `<button type="submit" >Submit</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with formData.append:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', input.files[0]);
```